# MYSQL 8.0 Connection With PHP 5.6

Tags: php, mysql

I Have installed mysql 8.0 and try to connect it with php 5.6 and getting following error.

Warning: mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the clien

Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: 2054 Debugging error: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Answer (score 0):

the `mysqli` library It may not be support on some servers; Use `PDO`instead.
Use these codes for connecting to Database with `PDO`:

```
    <?php
    $Host = "localhost";
    $dataBase = ""; //Write here the Name of Database
    $userName = ""; //Write here your username
    $Password = ""; //Write here your password
    $setName = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>'SET NAMES utf8');

    try{
        $connect = new PDO("mysql:host = $Host;dbname = $dataBase",$userName,$Password,$setName);
        echo 'Success...';
    }catch(PDOException $error) {
        echo 'Error !'. $error->getmessage();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation of what problem the code solves and why.

Comment: Yes, Sorry, I am editing my answer, Thank you for your reminder

Comment: Are you suggesting that it's the mysqli library that's missing? That's not what the error is about. The issue is that mysqli simply doesn't support the new default authentication method in MySQL 8.

Comment: thanks mithridates0

Comment: you're welcome Anuj

Comment: Step 1)  add the following line into etc/mysql/my.cnf 
[mysqld]
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

Step 2) ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';

Step 3) Use PDO instead mysqli

Comment: Thanks, @AnujMishra. It worked for me like a charm.